# XUbuntu 13.10. Не работают виртуальные хосты

Tags: apache

XUbuntu 13.10. Стоит lamp + Webmin. Создаешь вебмином виртуальные хосты, пишешь их в файле hosts.
/etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/home/anton/vhosts/phpmyadmin"
ServerName phpmyadmin
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
<Directory "/home/anton/vhosts/phpmyadmin">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1    localhost phpmyadmin
127.0.1.1    anton-MS-7392

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

$ curl -sH "Host: phpmyadmin" http://127.0.0.1/
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
```

То есть сервак не видит заголовка с виртуальником

```
$ apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
*:*                    is a NameVirtualHost
         default server phpmyadmin (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:1)
         port * namevhost phpmyadmin (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:1)
         port * namevhost phpmyadmin (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: Выделите текст и воспользуйтесь волшебной кнопочкой

![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/UcgcXyN.png

Comment: И оба хоста отмечены как default. Попробуйте для phpmyadmin:

    <VirtualHost *:80>

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать сим-линку

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Или использовать специальные для этого команды:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo a2ensite phpmyadmin.conf
```

И перезагрузить апач:

```
service apache2 reload
```

Должно работать.

Comment: Они там вроде бы есть уже. Я сейчас не дома. Что если сие не поможет?